# Independent Study Statistics/Probability Grad Level

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, references

I am trying to decide on topics for my independent study this semester. I am a Pre-Doctoral Mathematics student, so looking for a more math based text rather than engineering based (which I have found a lot of). I have already taken extensive courses in probability and statistics. Looking for something more challenging and more proof based considering I have background in analysis. Know of any textbooks?

Comment: Mathematical statistics and data analysis, by John A. Rice

Comment: Please see [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=math+stat*+grad*+%5Breferences%5D+answers%3A1) for previous questions like this one.